# How to get output of count variable?

Tags: php

```
<?php
$count=0;

class My extends Thread
{
     private $myid;

    //  ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
    //echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."<br/>";

    public function __construct($id)
    {
        $this->myid = $id;
    }

    public function run()
    {

    for($t=0;$j+$t<=100;$t+=10){ //future  buy
        for($k=0;$j+$t+$k<=100;$k+=10){//future sell
            for($l=1;$l<=14;$l++){ // strike
                for($m=0;$j+$k+$m<=300;$m+=10){ //put buy
                    for($n=1;$n<=14;$n++){ // strike
                        for($o=0;$o<=300;$o+=10){ // call buy
                            for($p=1;$p<=14;$p++){ //strike
                                if($p==$l)
                                    continue;                               
                                for($q=0;$q<=300;$q+=10){ // put sell
                                    for($r=1;$r<=14;$r++){ // strike
                                        if($r==$n)
                                            continue;
                                        for($s=0;$s<=300;$s+=10){ // call buy
                                            $count ++;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }                   
                    }
                }
            }
            }
        }   
    }

}
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."<br/>";

    $mycalls = [];
    for($i=0;$i<=100;$i+=10)
    {
        $mycalls[$i]= new My($i);
        $mycalls[$i]->start();
        $mycalls[$i]->join();
    }

    echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."<br/>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo $count;


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Call run method of My class. and it should be either return $count or echo $count.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I completely understand what you mean by "how to get output of count variable", but I see a number of problems there might occur.

1) $count is a global variable and not a class or a method variable, which menas that simply adding 1 to count in th run method will not do any changes in $count outside the class definition.

2) I don't see any place where run method that updates $count (despite the fact that it is outside the class) variable is called.

3) Even if run method is somewhere called  you have to add a line global $count at the beginning of run method.

4) I would suggest you store the $count internally in the class and return it with a function, which would mean that the class looks something like this:

```
Class My extends Thread{
    protected $count = 0;
    public function run(){
        //...
        $this -> count++;
        //...
    }

    public function getCount(){
        return $this -> count();
    }
}
```

And then get the count value from the class instance:

```
$myInstance = new My();
$myInstance -> run();
$someCount = $myInstance -> getCount();
```

Due to the fact that you are creating 101 instances of my, the code would look something like this:

```
$mycalls = [];
$count = 0;
for($i=0;$i<=100;$i+=10)
{
    $mycalls[$i]= new My($i);
    $mycalls[$i]->start();
    $mycalls[$i]->join();
    $count += $mycalls[$i] -> getCount();
}
echo $count;
```

Comment: is there any need of constructor in this programme?